# How to align mat-button with mat-input?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-input

How can I get these two items to align properly? I am trying to get them perfectly aligned but adjusting the button height just makes the bottom have get further away from the bottom of the search input. I think its because the center of them are not aligned so adjusting the height isn't really the correct solution.
  [image]

Here's the HTML

```
<!-- Search Box and Button-->
    <p>Search by company name:</p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 
        <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Search">
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Search</button>
```

Here's the SCSS:

```
mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 300px;
  }

  button.mat-stroked-button {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with your code ;)

Answer (score 5):

To achieve horizontal alignment you need to make some adjustment in markup and use flex properties for perfect alignment. I have added few div as parent but if you want you can assign CSS to actual parent classes of your code. I have added my snippet code below, update HTML and CSS accordingly :

```css
.searchcontainer {
          text-align:center;
          width: 100%;
          max-width: 600px;
          margin: 0 auto;
       }

       .searchcontainer .search-part {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
       }

      mat-form-field.mat-form-field {
          font-size: 12px;
          width: 300px;
      }

      button.mat-stroked-button {
          font-size: 14px;
          height: 42px;
          margin: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="searchcontainer">

      <p>Search by company name:</p>

      <div class="search-part">

        <mat-form-field appearance="outline"> 
            <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Search">
        </mat-form-field>

        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary">Search</button>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: A shame that they did not provide a way to do it natively.
Plus, if you zoom, it won't be beautiful.

Comment: Hack not a solution angular team stoped listening to developers a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Type Postcode</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Postcode" formControlName="postCode" required>
  <button matSuffix mat-button (click)=""><mat-icon >search</mat-icon></button>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image]